# Separating multi-valued attributes into individual attributes R

Tags: r, data-mining

I'm working with the stackoverflow developer survey data-set and attempting to predict compensation based on technologies worked with and collaborative tools worked with. These two attributes are multi-valued with semicolons separating the individual values.

For instance, under the CollabToolsWorkedWith attribute in one row, there is Confluence;Jira;Github;Slack;Microsoft;Teams;Google Suite. I want to give each of these values their own column with a value of either 0 or 1 if the row had that value.

The end result would have each row contain a column for every single value under CollabToolsWorkedWith and each column would contain 0's and 1's based on whether or not the row contained that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get a quicker answer next time if you provide some sample data that everyone can quickly access. I found the 2020 data online. Here is my answer:

```
# read the data frame
rm(list = ls())
df <- read.csv("survey_results_public.csv")

# figure out which column you are talking about
data.frame(colnames(df))
table(df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith)

# convert to lower case and character
df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith <- as.character(df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith)
df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith <- tolower(df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith)

#  keep only the useful variables and separate based on ;
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)
namesdf <- df %>% select(NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith) 
namesdf <- cSplit(namesdf,"NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith", sep = ";", direction = "wide", drop=TRUE, 
                  type.convert = TRUE) 

# stack stuff on top of each other to find unique list of tools/platforms
long_data_frame <-
  namesdf %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith"), # use columns starting with "year"
               names_to ="unique", # name of new column
               names_prefix = "_", 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  distinct(value)

# clean the variable names
library(janitor)
long_data_frame$value = as.character(long_data_frame$value)
long_data_frame$value = janitor::make_clean_names(long_data_frame$value)

# get final unique list
table(long_data_frame$value)

> table(long_data_frame$value)

                confluence         facebook_workplace                     github                     gitlab 
                         1                          1                          1                          1 
google_suite_docs_meet_etc                       jira            microsoft_azure            microsoft_teams 
                         1                          1                          1                          1 
                     slack   stack_overflow_for_teams                     trello 
                         1                          1                          1 

# create new variables
df$confluence <- NA
df$jira <- NA
df$slack = NA
df$microsoft_azure =NA
df$trello = NA
df$github = NA
df$gitlab = NA
df$google_suite_docs_meet_etc = NA
df$microsoft_teams = NA
df$stack_overflow_for_teams = NA
df$facebook_workplace =NA

# make a dummy variable based on string match
df$confluence <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "confluence", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$jira <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "jira", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$slack <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "slack", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$microsoft_azure <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "microsoft azure", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$trello <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "trello", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$github <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "github", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$gitlab <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "gitlab", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$google_suite_docs_meet_etc <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "google", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$microsoft_teams <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "microsoft teams", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$stack_overflow_for_teams <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "overflow", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))
df$facebook_workplace <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "facebook", x = df$NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith))

# proof that it went through 
table(df$facebook_workplace)

> table(df$facebook_workplace)

    0     1 
62881  1580
```

Comment: Mike, since you're using "splitstackshape", you should be able to just do `cSplit_e(df, "NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith", sep = ";", type = "character", fill = 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1! I tried your suggestion, and, although both your method and mine gave the same results, yours was indeed much more direct. `splitstackshape` is truly a terrific package. The `listCol_w` command, in particular, has saved me on numerous occasions. I didn't know about that `fill` functionality--thanks for alerting me to it.  @Richard Parker, are you satisfied? Do you want to close this?

Comment: Is there another way to achieve the same result without the library tidyverse? It will not install on my version of R studio.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for the feedback, and glad to help out.

Comment: @RichardParker, If you're able to install "splitstackshape", you should be able to use the suggestion I made in [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156888/separating-multi-valued-attributes-into-individual-attributes-r/63159331?noredirect=1#comment111700193_63159331).

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Wow I didn't realize that command did everything in one line, thank you! That's an incredible use.

Comment: @RichardParker you need first install [R Tools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to install and use the `tidyverse`. It is definitely worth your time. It's becoming tough to do data science without the tidyverse these days.